# How do I combine two SQL Queries, and uniquely label each in my output?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to determine sales difference in a percentage between two different groups, "Millennials," and all others ("Non-Millennials"). I am able to obtain total sales for each group through the following SQL queries:

```
SELECT SUM(f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price) AS 'Millenial Total Sales'
FROM Date_Dimension d, Order_Fact f, Item_Dimension i, Customer_Dimension c
WHERE i.Item_key = f.Item_key
AND c.DOB BETWEEN '1984-01-01' and '2000-12-25' 

SELECT SUM(f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price) AS 'Non-Millenial Total Sales'
FROM Date_Dimension d, Order_Fact f, Item_Dimension i, Customer_Dimension c
WHERE i.Item_key = f.Item_key
AND c.DOB NOT BETWEEN '1984-01-01' and '2000-12-25'
```

I have also used UNION, but I keep coming up with errors everytime I attempt percentages:

```
SELECT SUM(f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM Date_Dimension d, Order_Fact f, Item_Dimension i, Customer_Dimension c
WHERE i.Item_key = f.Item_key
AND c.DOB BETWEEN '1984-01-01' and '2000-12-25' 
UNION
SELECT SUM(f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM Date_Dimension d, Order_Fact f, Item_Dimension i, Customer_Dimension c
WHERE i.Item_key = f.Item_key
AND c.DOB NOT BETWEEN '1984-01-01' and '2000-12-25'
```

In a nutshell, how do I compare the two groups, "Millennial" and Non-Millennial", and show the percentage of sales for Millennials?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` to sum only millennials:

```
SELECT  *
,       100 * [Millennial Sales] / [Total Sales] as PercentageMillennialSales
FROM    (
        SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN c.DOB BETWEEN '1984-01-01' and '2000-12-25' 
                       THEN f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price END) AS [Millennial Sales]
        ,       SUM(f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price) AS [Total Sales]
        FROM    Date_Dimension d
        JOIN    Order_Fact f
        ON      ???
        JOIN    Item_Dimension i
        ON      ???
        JOIN    Customer_Dimension c
        ON      ???
        ) sub
```

Not sure how your tables are joined together.  If you don't get that right, the resulting numbers won't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing where you are linking the c table to the other tables. As it is, I think you are just doing a cross join, which means that you're effectively querying all the Order_Fact records each time, since there's no filtering link between c and f, and the only real filtering is on c.

So I just fabricated a connection where I'm guessing one is appropriate. You'll need to modify this to fit your tables, but something like the following should work:

```
SELECT Millenials.TotalM AS MillenialTotal, NonMillenials.TotalM AS NonMillenialTotal, (Millenials.TotalM/(Millenials.TotalM+NonMillenials.TotalM)) AS MillenialPercent
FROM (SELECT 
    SUM(f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price) AS Total
    FROM Order_Fact f 
        INNER JOIN Item_Dimension i ON i.Item_key = f.Item_key
        INNER JOIN Customer_Dimension c ON i.Customer_key = c.Customer_key
    WHERE c.DOB BETWEEN '1984-01-01' and '2000-12-25') AS Millenials
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 
    SUM(f.Quantity * f.Unit_Price) AS Total
    FROM Order_Fact f 
        INNER JOIN Item_Dimension i ON i.Item_key = f.Item_key
        INNER JOIN Customer_Dimension c ON i.Customer_key = c.Customer_key
    WHERE c.DOB NOT BETWEEN '1984-01-01' and '2000-12-25') AS NonMillenials
```